# Kylo Stepper-UI Plugin

Tags: apache, plugins, kylo

I'm trying to implement a Kylo Stepper-UI to add a custom page/step to the Feed Creation Wizard. The only tutorial available to do this https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/plugins/example-ui-feed-stepper-plugin

It isn't very descriptive and I'm finding it hard to follow. Can someone who's done this before give me a step by step way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to get the sample working? If you build that maven project and copy the jar file to kylo-ui/plugin/ and restart kylo-ui, then you should see the new option when you add or edit a template.

Comment: I have no clue where to start. I'm not able to get the sample to work

Comment: I tried building the sample using maven but I get a build error 

"Failed to execute goal on project example-ui-feed-stepper-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.kylo.plugin:example-ui-feed-stepper-plugin:jar:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.thinkbiganalytics.kylo:kylo-ui-api:jar:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: Try running `mvn -am -pl samples/plugins/example-ui-feed-stepper-plugin install -DskipTests`

Comment: I was able to build the jar and I copied it to /opt/kylo/kylo-ui/plugins

Then, I restarted Kylo. I see no changes in the UI. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You should see the new option when editing a template. Please double-check the file permissions of the jar. Also, please attach your /var/log/kylo-ui/kylo-ui.log file and attach a screenshot of the edit template page.